# Android speaker recognition

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to find out of there is any Speech(or Voice) API(for Android) which can be used for recognition of the speaker. My aim is creating application which is going to recognize the speaker and differentiate it from another person, which can serve like authentication.

Thanks in advance,
Serhiy.

Comment: Hi Serhiy, did you got any solution for your problem? Can you please share it with us.. I am also searching for such solution.

Comment: solution used was recording some frames of the speech(not entire talk but some parts) and doing such validation server side, thought the ratio of the false positive is still quite high..

Comment: @Serhiy hello, Good question, thumbs up for that, Did you solve the problem. I need help regards the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll have much luck with the Recognizer intent, which is used to convert speech to text. I'm not aware of anything that does speaker recognition. But you could use AudioRecord to grab raw audio frames and then do signal processing on them. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with exactly which audio processors would help you differentiate one speaker from another though.

Comment: Yeah, speech to text is not the thing I want. Probably you are right the only way of doing so is working with raw data and generate some kind of hash for every new entry I'm getting and compare it to the existing one or ones. Just was wondering maybe some1 already made something like this for Android, because JSAPI(Java Speech API), which could be a solution isn't compatible with Android.. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You could toy around with android.media. To my knowledge there is no java sound api fully ported to android.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. I think I can get raw data from android.media.AudioRecord read method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Android SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-SpeakerRecognition-Android) of [Microsoft Speaker Recognition Service](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speaker-recognition-api).

It supports both speaker verification and speaker identification.

Here's a link to all [the availbe SDKs and sample apps](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/SDK-Sample?api=speaker%20recognition).